# Error while reading property file using @PropertySource in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I am new to Spring-Boot application and trying to read external property file in my Spring Boot application which is in my **resource folder besides application.properties**, but getting following exception,

[image]

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.test.config.MyInetgrationApplicationConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/myIntegration.properties]
2017-09-06 17:27:04.866 ERROR 10512 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@225fa519: startup date [Wed Sep 06 17:27:04 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414) [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
```

My Config class is as follows,

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(name="myIntegrationProperties", value ="myIntegration.properties")
public class MyInetgrationApplicationConfig {

    /**
     * Rest template.
     *
     * @return the rest template
     */
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Value("${datasource.name}")
    private String dataSourceName;

    @Value("${datasource.driver}")
    private String dataSourceDriver;

    @Value("${datasource.url}")
    private String dataSourceUrl;

    @Value("${datasource.username}")
    private String dataSourceUserName;

    @Value("${datasource.password}")
    private String dataSourcePassword;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setName(dataSourceName);
        dataSource.setUrl(dataSourceUrl);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dataSourceDriver);
        dataSource.setUsername(dataSourceUserName);
        dataSource.setPassword(dataSourcePassword);

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

My Application class,

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.test" })
public class MyInetgrationApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyInetgrationApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get values using `@Value("${datasource.name}")` so I have tried after autowiring the `Environment` and then using `environment.getProperty("datasource.name")` it worked for me.
Following is the sample code,

```
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:myIntegration.properties")
    public class MyInetgrationApplicationConfig {

        @Autowired
        private Environment environment;

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
            dataSource.setName(environment.getProperty("datasource.name"));
            dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("datasource.url"));
            .
            .
            .
            .
            return dataSource;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add claapath:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:myIntegration.properties")
```

The `myIntegration.properties` file should be placed under /src/main/resources so that it will be available on the `classpath` at runtime.

Comment: I have tried by aading "classpath:" but again getting following exception,

BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myApplicationConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'datasource.driver' in value "${datasource.driver}

Comment: That error is related to `myApplicationConfig`, not related to PropertySource. Post your code of `myApplicationConfig`.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/ here you can get it with all the in-depth details.

Comment: Sorry for typo, Its MyInetgrationApplicationConfig only.

 BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myInetgrationApplicationConfig ': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'datasource.driver' in value "${datasource.driver}

Should I have to exclude some AutoConfguration of DataSource?

Comment: Have you added `@ComponentScan("your structure")` to class where you've implemented `main` method.

Comment: Yes, I have added my class above in question.

Comment: I am not able to see main method in class. Please add full code.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving classpath reference to you resource file path, as below:

```
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:myIntegration.properties" }, name="myIntegrationProperties")
```